# Why is the result using the code below different when display is not used for input?

Tags: list, replace, scheme, display

SCHEME PROGRAMMING

The output of this code is different from the input using display. How can I make it work using the input in the interactive window?

input: `` (list-replace `(1 3 5 15 9)) ``

output: `(shared ((-2- "T-ICE")) (list 2 -2- 7 -2- 8 "T"))`

Using `` (display(list-replace `(1 3 5 15 9)) ``
output: `(1 "T" "ICE" "T-ICE" "T")`

```
(define (list-replace li)
(cond
((null? li) li)

((and (= (modulo (car li) 3) 0) (= (modulo (car li) 5) 0)) (cons "T-ICE" (list-replace(cdr li))))

((= (modulo (car li) 3) 0) (cons "T" (list-replace(cdr li))))

((= (modulo (car li) 5) 0) (cons "ICE" (list-replace(cdr li))))

(else (cons (car li) (list-replace(cdr li))))))
```

Comment: Which scheme implementation are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this is to go to the "Languages menu", then select "Choose Language ...". At the bottom of the dialog, click "Show Details", and at the bottom of the 
"Output Syntax" group on the right, uncheck the box labeled "Show 
sharing in values".